# Installation of Tkinter

Tags: python, installation, download, tkinter

Where can I download this programm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any recent version of Python should come with Tkinter support.  To my knowledge, you shouldn't need to install anything else.

Answer (score 2):

As a standard python library, Tkinter is part of any standard Python installation. You can can get a standard python installation at http://www.python.org/download/.

Answer (score -2):

If you worked on linux , and you don't have the root privilege . You need to install python locally. You can't use like the following commands:

```
apt-get install python-tk
sudo apt-get install python-tk
```

You can get the tcl/tk right here http://www.tcl.tk/software/tcltk/download.html. And then refer to this [Install tkinter  and python locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11948295/install-tkinter-and-python-locally)

Comment: This is incorrect. You gave instructions for installing tk, not tkinter.

Comment: sometimes ,if you don't have the privillege or you want to install them locally. you need to installl the tcl/tk by yourself. and then use the Python will generate the tkinter module

Comment: while that may be true, your answer is pretty much useless for the person asking the question unless you show how. Explaining only half of the solution doesn't help anyone.

Comment: thanks, I should ansower the queestion detailedly, Thanks for your suggessions