# Install tkinter and python locally

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit

I work with linux on a servies. And I don't have the root privilege. I installed the python-3.2.3 locally to "/home/sam/install_sam".  when I import the tkinter module. I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named _tkinter, please install the python-tk package
```

I know I need to install the Tkinter module. because I don't have the root privilege. I can't use like the  following commands:

```
apt-get install python-tk
sudo apt-get install python-tk
```

And I search on goolge. **I get tcl/tk from** [here](http://www.tcl.tk/software/tcltk/download.html). I install them use the following commands.

```
cd ~/Downloads/tcl8.5.11/unix
./configure --prefix=/home/sam/install_sam/tcl
make
make install

cd ~/Downloads/tk8.5.11/unix
./configure --prefix=/home/sam/install_sam/tk 
            --with- tcl=/home/sam/Downloads/tcl8.5.11/unix
make
make install

cd ~/Downloads/Python3.2.3/
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/sam/install_sam/tcl/lib:/home/sam/install_sam/tk/lib
export LD_RUN_PATH=/home/sam/install_sam/tcl/lib:/home/sam/install_sam/tk/lib
./configure --prefix=/home/sam/install_sam/python 
make
make install
```

I still got error: **INFO: Can't locate Tcl/Tk libs and/or headers**. How should I config the tcl/tk for the python

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use CPPFLAGS environment variable to set the include directories for tcl and tk before building Python 3.  This has worked for me.

```
export CPPFLAGS="-I/home/sam/install_sam/tcl/include -I/home/sam/install_sam/tk/include"
```

Answer (score 7):

Finally. I install tcl/tk and python in a same path. It can work now. the commands as follow:

```
cd ~/Downloads/tcl8.5.11/unix
./configure --prefix=/home/sam/install_sam/python3
make
make install

cd ~/Downloads/tk8.5.11/unix
./configure --prefix=/home/sam/install_sam/python3
            --with-tcl=/home/sam/Downloads/tcl8.5.11/unix
make
make install

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/sam/install_sam/python3/lib
cd ~/Downloads/Python3.2.3/3
./configure --prefix=/home/sam/install_sam/python3 
make
make install
```

someone can tell me **how to config the tcl/tk for python in the first way(mentioned in the question)**. I'll appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install tcl-dev tk-dev
```

worked for me, although I ended up pulling a docker image and using that instead.

Comment: Worked for me. Though I had to recompile and re-install python again. I compiled python3,7 from source in Ubuntu16.04 since deadsnakes is no longer supported

Answer (score 1):

For CentOS, this is:

```
yum install -y tcl-devel tk-devel
```

Worked on CentOS 7.

In general, I find that where RHEL has `*-dev`, CentOS has `*-devel`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had `import tkinter` properly working on my Python3 environment, but I had to use a pre-compiled Python with its own environment (Blender fyi) that didn't include the dependencies (I needed tkinter to run `matplotlib`).

The fix in my case was very simple:

1. In the **working** python, `import tkinter` and check where it is installed with `tkinter.__file__`. This will be something like `path/to/site-packages/tkinter`
2. Copy the `tkinter` folder into the `site-packages`of your target installation
3. Then `import _tkinter` won't work. Again using the file trick, locate the missing `.so` file, in my Ubuntu was something like `path/to/python3.7/lib-dynload/_tkinter.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
4. Again, copy the `.so` file into the corresponding `lib-dynload` of your target installation. **Make sure that both origin and target Python versions are compatible**.

To make sure that your target python finds the copied files, make sure that the destination paths are listed under `sys.path`.

Hope this helps!
Cheers,
Andres