# matplotlib - no module named tkinter in Blender python

Tags: python, tkinter, blender

I am trying to write a `blender` script for which I need `matplotlib.pyplot`. When trying to `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'tkinter'
```

However, using the installed `anaconda` version, the import is no problem. The common [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36327323/3881984) to run

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

does not solve the problem. 
I tried to add the Path to `tkinter` with:

```
sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python3.4/tkinter/')

sys.path.append('/home/<username>/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/tkinter/')
```

Both commands did not resolve the error.

Comment: Did you try to install tkinter using pip: "pip install tkinter"

Comment: I was not aware that this is possible. Using `tkinter` or `python3-tk` both result in `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for tkinter`

Comment: It's tkinter, not tkiter

Comment: Sorry. Just a typo. But same error message from `pip`. I read that, since it is a `C++` package, it cannot be installed via `pip`

Comment: I am using anaconda distro, and it run well without above issue :)

Comment: The `pip` command ran well or the import of `pyplot`. My problem is not with the anaconda distribution but with Blenders own python distribution.

Comment: First check your versions. Blender 2.78 uses python 3.5, trying to use modules built for python 3.4 and/or 3.6 will cause issues.There are several [ways](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5287/935) to access third party python modules, if it is only your use you may find removing blenders copy of python the easiest so that it uses the system python.

Comment: Does the system python also need to be 3.5 to work with blender? What would be the alternative, if deleting was not an option?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to import `tkinter` (and use it with `matplotlib.pyplot`) from Blender as I explained here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56050748/4511978

Hope it helps!
Andres

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you shouldn’t need to mess around with `pip` to install `tkinter`, since it’s a standard Python module. Also the Blender package should use the system Python, so it will have access to all system Python modules.

**But** ... `tkinter` is a GUI framework, and trying to use this will conflict with Blender’s own GUI.

Another option might be to use Matplotlib in offscreen-plotting mode, which doesn’t need a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching the backend from `tkinter` to `agg` using -

`matplotlib.use('agg')`