# Installing Python 3.12 with custom TCL/TK on RHEL 7

Tags: python, redhat, rhel7, python-3.12

I am trying to build Python 3.12 with TCL/TK on RHEL 7.

I have 0 root privileges. My system build is HORRIBLY outdated. I have no control over this and cannot update/use package installers, which is why I've gone through this 'compiling from source' endeavor.

After digging around I found that there WAS a configure option in the past for --with-tcltk... but those options were removed. After looking in the whatsnew, I found that you can specify the custom locations using the envvars TCLTK_CFLAGS and TCLTK_LIBS. My tcl/tk installations are not in the same directory, they are under $HOME/.../tcl8.6 and $HOME/.../tk8.6 respectively. (I'm using abs path on the envvars)

I know I'm close, but after building using these variables I still can't import tkinter after compiling python3.12.1 on RHEL 7.

I have not found any information as to how to use those variables, which paths I need to specify/what is necessary or any examples of how to do this.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11948295/install-tkinter-and-python-locally help here?

Comment: No, that was removed I think starting 3.11. I posted a solution that worked for me. I just needed to set up the env vars correctly. Since I'm new to building from source these CFLAGS are foreign to me but I found the right approach. Unfortunately, it seems they may remove this option starting 3.13 and force the usage of autoconf instead. This is bad for me because that will be yet another program that I will need to manually compile ....

Comment: You're on a nearly-EOL version of red hat, without root access. Compiling yet another program from source just to get anything done should be second nature by now =D (but on a serious note, nice find, I'm sure others will appreciate your answer post)

Answer (score 3):

OK, found the answer to anyone who may have a similar issue. I was on the right track, but I missed -tcl8.6 and -tk8.6 options on the TCLTK_LIBS envvar.

Here is a link to the source of the post that helped me figure this out: [Solution](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/2499#issuecomment-1292424083)

I placed all the settings onto a script.

***In order to load tkinter, you'll need to export LD_LIBRARY_PATH with the tcl/tk/ssl library directories before starting python. Exporting this env var screws with a program that out workstations rely on, so I need to do this everytime I load python.

```
#!/bin/bash

#My source locations; yours will differ
bin_path="$HOME/bin"
src_path="/mnt/netapp_data/bin/src"

python_source="$bin_path/src/sourcefiles/Python-3.12.1"
python_dest="$bin_path/src/python/python3.12"

ssl="$src_path/openssl"
tk="$src_path/tk8.6"
tcl="$src_path/tcl8.6"

# Need to export these vars; need '-L{lib_dir} -l{lib}' per library apparently
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$tcl/lib:$tk/lib:$ssl/lib
export TCLTK_CFLAGS="-I$tcl/include -I$tk/include"
export TCLTK_LIBS="-L$tcl/lib -ltcl8.6 -L$tk/lib -ltk8.6"

#This is pretty standard after setting up the env vars
cd $python_source
./configure --prefix=$python_dest --with-openssl=$ssl --with-ensurepip=install
make -j4
make install
```