# How to install Tkinter on debian sid?

Tags: python, tkinter, debian

I need to install tkinter on debian. After some research[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640880/installation-of-tkinter)[[2]](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/How_to_install_Tkinter), I noticed that Tkinter should be automatically installed with Python. However, when I try to import the module, I get the following:

```
>>> import tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named tkinter
```

When I try to import Tkinter, the error changes:

```
>>> import Tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 42, in <module>
    raise ImportError, str(msg) + ', please install the python-tk package'
ImportError: No module named _tkinter, please install the python-tk package
```

So I try to install the python-tk package via apt-get. Another error comes out:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/t/tk8.5/tk8.5_8.5.14-2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
```

I'm on debian sid, amd64.

Comment: Is your `sources.list` correct? what is content of it?

Comment: I guess so. deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable main contrib non-free  
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable main contrib non-free

Comment: `tkinter` failed because that's a 3.x package and it seems you are running 2.7.

Comment: But in python2.X, tkinter was called Tkinter, right? It's also not working when I try to import it.

Comment: [Yes](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter#Step_2_-_can_Tkinter_be_imported.3F), for `Python 2.X` is `import Tkinter` and for `Python 3.X` is `import tkinter`. so you just need to install `python-tk` debian package.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm facing problems to install the package, as I mentioned on the question :(

Comment: First do `apt-get update` and then `apt-get install python-tk`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems your packages list is out of date, first retrieve new lists of packages by:

```
apt-get update
```

And then install `tk` package with:

```
apt-get install python-tk
```

Or, for Python 3:

```
apt-get install tk
```

Answer (score 7):

I followed Omid Raha's answer, but I had to use

```
apt-get update
apt-get install python3-tk
```

in order to get it working in python3.