# Python Problem on Debian with importing and using Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, linux, debian

At the beginning I had some trouble to install anything from the python library but then I found this post which fixed my problem not being able to install anything with pip.

But now I want to install Tkinter on my Debian an it does not work.

I get following Error Message in Visual Studio Code:

Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'tkinter'
File "/home/jb/Dokumente/Visual Studio Code/Python/Projekt01/main.py", line 2, in 
import tkinter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and can help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Tkinter on debian sid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22873043/how-to-install-tkinter-on-debian-sid)